# Emphasize contours

Tags: images, software-recommendation, photo-editing

My profile picture's eye contours are fairly dim, I wish to emphasize them. Left is original, right is my attempt with MS Paint:

[image]

Not so great, particularly if zooming. Is there a tool to achieve this effect? I could e.g. paste a filtered version over original.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Those details probably are too small to work well in a profile - they'll almost completely disappear when viewed at small sizes. What is wrong with the attempt you've made?  What do you mean by a filter? A filter to do what? Sorry but I don't really understand what you are asking here.

Comment: @BillyKerr Agreed it's a non-issue if small, but it's not always small. Filter e.g. contrast, sharpening, etc. - crop out the eyes, apply an effect, then overlay with original. Regarding my attempt, if we view it full size, it's clear that it's just black dots placed with a cursor - looks 'unnatural'. The goal's to make the "circles" more visible.

Comment: There are sharpening filters if that's what you mean.  Available in software such as Photoshop (not free), or GIMP (which is free).  You'd basically make a selection around the eyes, then apply a sharpening filter, such as Unsharp Mask.

Comment: @BillyKerr Great, thanks. I used GIMP, `Filters > Enhance > Sharpen (Unsharp Mask)` with `Radius = 1.3, Amount = 2.8`, then cropped out everything but the eyes and overlaid on original. Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Sharpen (Unsharp Mask) in GIMP, also possible in Photoshop.

Make a selection of the eyes, and then apply the filter

[image]